# tortoisehg on mac connect to repository

Tags: macos, tortoisehg-2.0

I've already download tortoisehg from http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io. And I need download repository form the web. I'm create new repository but I don't now where set my url and name for repository. Could u help me ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to download repository from web, you have not create local repository, but clone remote repository (into empty local directory). URL of remote source will be stored in local clone automatically.

"My name" is too common and unclean term, can say nothing without additional details: **write your business-task** here